# How do I exclude commented lines from searches in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5

Is it possible to exclude commented lines (either individual, or groups) from searches in Xcode?

If so, how can this be done?

Comment: i think NO. but you can try to search scopes it has more efficiently comes from xcode 5

Comment: Question is closed but I found a very useful solution.
You can quickly skip any comment when looking at the list: Comments will have the white icon on the left of the line (can't add screenshot in comment) so you don't have to go to each line!
So you can't search and exclude them but you can save the time anyways!

Comment: the white icon is not reliable. it is also used to indicate 'term exist in some string'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot exclude comment lines from Xcode search.

You can use "search scopes" to search more efficiently in Xcode:

[image: Xcode search scopes]

Reference by [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012953-SW1):

> The refined search navigator allows all current search options and settings to be seen at a glance. The options are easily manipulated by clicking directly on them in the search navigator. You can set search scopes, including selecting multiple folders in a project, and save them by name for easy re-use. The search results display wraps to allow you to see ore results easily and quickly.